# Avoid require statement in the transpiled javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

The following statements from a `.ts` file:

```
import {jquery as $} from 'jquery';
import {socketio} from 'socket.io';
```

get transpiled to:

```
var jquery_1 = require("jquery");
var socket_io_1 = require("socket.io");
```

Now the browser won't recognize `require`. What is the way out? My `tsconfg.json` looks like:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmitOnError": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "include": [
        "index.ts",
        "./lib/**/*",
        "./public/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Is there a need to change something?

Comment: Use [AMD modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Comment: Generally you'd use Webpack.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Could you please help me with an example. I tried `browserify` but it throws a run time error saying it cannot find a certain module.

Comment: Browsers don't support CommonJS. You either need to tell TS to generate something that the browser supports (don't know TS so not sure what the options are), or use a module bundler. If browserify throws an error, then investigate how you can fix that error.

Answer (score 0):

I used [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to bundle the final file into a browser compatible javascript.

```
browserify input.js -o output.js
```

There could be errors thrown by the browserify saying for example `Error: Cannot find module 'bufferutil' from ..` In that case, the respective modules could be installed from the npm.